# Google spreadsheet - script throws "Exceeded maximum execution time" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following google script that will run against 500+ rows of data in the "InputFromHospital" sheet and in the middle of execution, getting the "*Exceeded maximum execution time*" error.

I was having few more lines of code but after reading the similar questions in StackOverflow, I removed and kept only the needed lines/source code. I am not sure how I could further optimize.

Looking for your suggestions/expertise to optimize and to reduce the execution time to under 5 minutes?

```
function feedToMasterAndPolice() {
  var ssbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ssbook.getSheetByName('MasterPatientData')
  var sLastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow() + 1
  var inputSheet = ssbook.getSheetByName('InputFromHospital')
  var iLastRow = inputSheet.getLastRow();
  var pSheet = ssbook.getSheetByName('DataToPolice')
  var pLastRow = pSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "dd/MMM/yyyy")

  //Loop thru all rows in "Input.." sheet
  for (var i = 2; i <= iLastRow; i++) {
    //Reading contact number from "Input.." sheet
    var value = inputSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var gID = "";
    if (value.toString.length > 0) {
      //Generating unique patient ID for each COVID Patient
      gID = "PID".concat(srcSheet.getLastRow());
      srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, 1).setValue(gID.toString());
      //Looping thru all 8 colums in "Input" sheet
      for (var colN = 2; colN < 9; colN++) {
        var actCellVal = inputSheet.getRange(i, colN).getValue();
         //Set value for contact# and date values
        if (colN == 5 || colN == 6 || colN == 8) {
          srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, colN).setValue(actCellVal)
        } else {
         //All String values - upper case
          srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, colN).setValue(actCellVal.toString().toUpperCase())
        }
      }

      var cR = srcSheet.getLastRow();
      //Adding formula to calculate "DAYS SINCE ADMISSION" - example =if(A2<>"",TODAY()-F2,"")
      srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, 9).setFormula("=if(A" + cR + "<>\"\",TODAY()-F" + cR + ",\"\")")
      //Adding formula to calculate "FOLLOW UP NEEDED" - example =if(I2<=Admin!$C$2,"YES","NO"
      srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, 10).setFormula("=if(I" + cR + "<=\'Admin\'!$C$2,\"YES\",\"NO\")");
      //Add current date
      srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, 11).setValue(todayDate);

      sLastRow = sLastRow + 1

    } else {
      //Above logic same when contact number is blank
      //Not considerd Patient ID #
      var ppID = "NCPID".concat(pSheet.getLastRow());
      //Untested
      pSheet.getRange(pLastRow, 1).clear();
      pSheet.getRange(pLastRow, 1).setValue(ppID.toString());
      //till above
      for (var colN = 2; colN <= 9; colN++) {
        var actCellVal = inputSheet.getRange(i, colN).getValue();
        if (colN == 6 || colN == 8) {
          pSheet.getRange(pLastRow, colN).setValue(actCellVal)
        } else {
          pSheet.getRange(pLastRow, colN).setValue(actCellVal.toString().toUpperCase())
          pSheet.getRange(pLastRow, 9).setValue(todayDate);
        }
      }
      pLastRow = pLastRow + 1
    }
  }
   //this.ClearAnySheet("InputFromHospital")
};
```

Sample file available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqb0fxdb4cVweL9SEqhC-eM5mN5ZleA-/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: In your script, can I ask you about what you want to do at `if (value.toString.length > 0)`?

Comment: If the phone # is empty, then it should go to "DataToPolice" sheet and above is the validation for the same.

Comment: Added comments for easier understanding.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Unfortunately, I cannot test above modified script with your actual situation. So when my proposed script cannot be used for your actual situation, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modified script:

```
function feedToMasterAndPolice_b() {
  var ssbook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ssbook.getSheetByName('MasterPatientData');
  var sLastRow = srcSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var inputSheet = ssbook.getSheetByName('InputFromHospital');
  var pSheet = ssbook.getSheetByName('DataToPolice');
  var pLastRow = pSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "dd/MMM/yyyy");


  var [, ...values] = inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var { masterPatientData, dataToPolice } = values.reduce((o, [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8], i) => {
    if (c5.toString() != "") {
      var last = sLastRow - 1 + o.masterPatientData.length;
      o.masterPatientData.push([
        `PID${last}`,
        ...[c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8].map((c, j) => [3, 4, 6].includes(j) ? c : c.toString().toUpperCase()),
        `=if(A${last + 1}<>"",TODAY()-F${last + 1},"")`,
        `=if(I${last + 1}<='Admin'!\$C\$2,"YES","NO")`,
        todayDate,
      ]);
    } else {
      var last = pLastRow - 1 + o.dataToPolice.length;
      o.dataToPolice.push([
        `NCPID${last}`,
        ...[c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8].map((c, j) => [4, 6].includes(j) ? c : c.toString().toUpperCase()),
        todayDate,
      ]);
    }
    return o;
  }, { masterPatientData: [], dataToPolice: [] });
  if (masterPatientData.length > 0) {
    srcSheet.getRange(sLastRow, 1, masterPatientData.length, masterPatientData[0].length).setValues(masterPatientData);
  }
  if (dataToPolice.length > 0) {
    pSheet.getRange(pLastRow, 1, dataToPolice.length, dataToPolice[0].length).setValues(dataToPolice);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot test above modified script with your actual situation. So when my proposed script cannot be used for your actual situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you, I tried the above code and I have now the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, also added the file for you in the question.

Comment: @Dhamo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, I cannot understand about your current situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill, again.

Comment: Thank you for being ready to help. I have already edited the question and added the spreadsheet. Alternatively, you can [click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vqb0fxdb4cVweL9SEqhC-eM5mN5ZleA-/view?usp=sharing) to get the same.

Comment: @Dhamo Thank you for replying and providing the sample. It seems that your sample is not Google Spreadsheet. But in your actual situation, that is the Google Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, please confirm my updated answer again. If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: @Dhamo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.